# Set Minimum Height of Print Paper Size?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, .net, media-queries

I have a label printer TSC TTP-244 Pro. This label printer prints 2 label at a time. Suppose I have only 2 labels to be printed, then because it is printing 2 label at a time it should print 2 labels. But it is printing 10 labels at a time with 2 labels printed and rest 8 labels are empty.[The output of printer in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LYpL.jpg)

But I want that the printer should print only 2 labels not 10 labels at a time. I am printing these labels through aspx page. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so silly. The functionality of adjusting the size, is already given in printer settings. Thanks for viewing it.